# Create a Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I would like to know if it is possible to create a template in any language, HTML, CSS, jQuery, JavaScript, etc.

> where I could create a template for my site with a header (with an
>   image), sidebar (for instance a selector, images, and somethingelse),
>   footer(with links to other pages like about page, contact us, etc),
>   and I central area where I introduce a different code an info to each
>   HTML page.

My idea is so I can modify only in one place the image of the header, the selector or the sidebar or any other element so it will change in all the HTML pages instead of having to have to change it in every single HTML page.

IF it is possible, how could I do it with the following selector?

Code:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Orange</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie if you want this done on the client side for when the page loads. 
Use database (or session) for more persistent change.
If you want the header to change in real time (to change to already loaded page) you would have to use something like nowjs (socket.io).

Comment: Sorry that I'm so new at this, but what you are telling me sound Chinese to me.